# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400 at createError (createError.js:16) at settle at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, mern

I am getting above error when i am fetching the data from axios , when all the validations are correct, i get the data , but when i try to send wrong data it gives me above error

```
import React from 'react'
import { TextField, Button } from '@mui/material';
import ArrowBackIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowBack';
import GoogleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Google';
import FacebookIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Facebook';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "../styles/home.css"
import useInputState from "../hooks/useInputState"
import axios from 'axios';

function Login() {

    const [username, updateUsername, resetUsername] = useInputState("")
    const [password, updatePassword, resetPassword] = useInputState("")
    const HOST = "http://localhost:8080"

    const handleSubmit = async (evt) => {
        evt.preventDefault()
        const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
        const data = JSON.stringify({ username, password })
        console.log(data)
        const response = await axios.post(`${HOST}/api/auth/login`, data, config)
        console.log(response.data)
        resetUsername()
        resetPassword()
        // if (resp.data.success) {
        //     console.log("redirecting to oppp")
        // } else {
        //     alert("invalid credentials")
        // }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="container mt-5 addnotes" >
                <Button className="mb-4" variant="text" color="secondary" startIcon={<ArrowBackIcon />} component={Link} to="/" style={{ textTransform: "none", fontFamily: "'Poppins', sans-serif" }}>Home</Button>
                <h2 style={{ fontWeight: "Bold" }}>Login</h2>
                <p className="mb-4">Sign in on the internal platform</p>
                <div className="d-flex">
                    <Button size="large" fullWidth className="mb-4 me-4" variant="contained" color="primary" startIcon={<FacebookIcon />} component={Link} to="/" style={{ textTransform: "none", fontSize: "1.1rem", color: "White", fontFamily: "'Poppins', sans-serif" }}>Login with Facebook</Button>
                    <Button size="large" fullWidth className="mb-4" variant="contained" color="error" startIcon={<GoogleIcon />} component={Link} to="/" style={{ textTransform: "none", fontSize: "1.1rem", color: "White", fontFamily: "'Poppins', sans-serif" }}>Login with Google</Button>
                </div>
                <p className="mb-4 d-flex justify-content-center">or login with username and password</p>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="mb-4">
                        <TextField value={username} onChange={updateUsername} inputProps={{ minLength: 1 }} color="secondary" label="Username" variant="outlined" fullWidth required style={{ textTransform: "none", fontFamily: "'Poppins', sans-serif", fontSize: "1.1rem" }} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="mb-4">
                        <TextField type="password" value={password} onChange={updatePassword} inputProps={{ minLength: 1 }} color="secondary" label="Password" variant="outlined" fullWidth required style={{ textTransform: "none", fontFamily: "'Poppins', sans-serif", fontSize: "1.1rem" }} />
                    </div>
                    <Button disabled={username.length < 1 || password.length < 1} type="submit" fullWidth size="large" className="mb-4" variant="contained" color="secondary" style={{ textTransform: "none", fontFamily: "'Poppins', sans-serif", fontSize: "1.1rem" }}>Add Note</Button>
                </form>
                <p>Don't have an account? <Link to="/register" >register</Link> </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

The error is occured in handlesubmit function when i try to give wrong input which should give me a response with an error but it gives me following error and the usernamereset and passwordReset does not get executed , but when i give correct username and password i get the correct data

Error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66)
```

Backend Code for that route:

```
router.post('/login', validateUserLogin, catchAsync(loginUser))
module.exports.loginUser = async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body
    const foundUser = await User.findAndValidate(username, password)
    if (foundUser) {
        const data = {
            user: { id: foundUser._id }
        }
        const authToken = jwt.sign(data, process.env.JWT_KEY)
        res.send({ success: true, authToken })
    } else {
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, err: { user: foundUser }, message: "invalid credentials !!" })
    }
}
```

when i am sending wrong password an username i am not getting this invalid credentials message

Comment: It seems that this is an error on back end and on in your code. What is the expected behavior.  Also, I suggest you have a then catch in your axios call.

Comment: i edited and uploaded backend code also

Comment: What is on line 16 at createError and line 17 at settle files?

Comment: i dont know bro

Comment: It could be then that the error is either in findAndValidate method or in jwt.sign

Comment: no bro because now i used fetch api instead of axios all is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

TL:DR: You're doing everything right

I suppose on the back end side, there is a handler which will check if your request is correct, and if it's not , will send you 400 code

[More on 400 error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400)

Comment: i will also send backend code of that route, pls tell me where is i am going wrong

Comment: Wrap your request in try/catch and console the error, i think wou will get the idea

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling error in `handlesubmit`

While using promises, either use `try-catch` if you are using `await`, or use `then` and `catch` to properly handler promise rejections.

In your code, axios will reject the promise in case of http code 400 and you are not handling that error anywhere, so any code after `await axios.post(`${HOST}/api/auth/login`, data, config);` won't run.

Use try-catch to properly handle that error.

```js
handleSubmit = async (evt) => {
        evt.preventDefault();
        try {
            const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } };
            const data = JSON.stringify({ username, password });
            console.log(data);
            const response = await axios.post(`${HOST}/api/auth/login`, data, config);
            console.log(response.data);
            resetUsername();
            resetPassword();
        } catch (err) {
            // do something when error occurrs
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Brother i used try and catch but further program code usernameReset and passwordReset function then also is not being executed